# GregorianCalendar - java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: MONTH

Tags: datetime, apache-spark, jdbc

While I tried to load mysql table with spark dataframe. 
I got error message.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: MONTH
  at java.util.GregorianCalendar.computeTime(GregorianCalendar.java:2648)
  at java.util.Calendar.updateTime(Calendar.java:3393)
  at java.util.Calendar.getTimeInMillis(Calendar.java:1782)
  at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.io.JdbcDateValueFactory.createFromDate(JdbcDateValueFactory.java:67)
  at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.io.JdbcDateValueFactory.createFromDate(JdbcDateValueFactory.java:39)
  at com.mysql.cj.core.io.ZeroDateTimeToNullValueFactory.createFromDate(ZeroDateTimeToNullValueFactory.java:41)
  at com.mysql.cj.core.io.BaseDecoratingValueFactory.createFromDate(BaseDecoratingValueFactory.java:46)
  at com.mysql.cj.core.io.BaseDecoratingValueFactory.createFromDate(BaseDecoratingValueFactory.java:46)
  at com.mysql.cj.core.io.MysqlTextValueDecoder.decodeDate(MysqlTextValueDecoder.java:66)
  at com.mysql.cj.mysqla.result.AbstractResultsetRow.decodeAndCreateReturnValue(AbstractResultsetRow.java:70)
  at com.mysql.cj.mysqla.result.AbstractResultsetRow.getValueFromBytes(AbstractResultsetRow.java:225)
  at com.mysql.cj.mysqla.result.TextBufferRow.getValue(TextBufferRow.java:122)
  at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.result.ResultSetImpl.getNonStringValueFromRow(ResultSetImpl.java:630)
  at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.result.ResultSetImpl.getDateOrTimestampValueFromRow(ResultSetImpl.java:643)
  at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.result.ResultSetImpl.getDate(ResultSetImpl.java:788)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$jdbc$JdbcUtils$$makeGetter$$.apply(JdbcUtils.scala:380)
```

Comment: Please add your code that you are using to load the table, the schema of the table and other details that you think could be relevant to the problem. In short, provide a [mcve].

Comment: Are there any bad date values in your table? For example a date of 0000-00-00?

Comment: Yes, I had bad value like '2018-00-00', '2018-01-00', '2018-00-01'. Working on spark 'JDBCDialects' to mitigate problems.

Comment: @ruseel it may help if you use getString on resultset, then try to convert it to date,if possible ofc... i came up with the same error and for my case, it was fine to use rs.getString("date_column_name"), then using date parser on it... not the best way though

Comment: In my case above, there was a row like '1900-00-00'. So with some table, I had to convert to string type with JDBCDialects. With other tables I just clean up table like update, delete.

Answer (score -2):

Try latest mysql 5.X.X JDBC driver.